# How could mega-biomes be possible?

Tags: internal-consistency

I was wading in a creek today and imagined if a little rock was the size of a person. Then I thought about how something like that would even be possible. I came up with a few ideas but am still unsure.

[image]
(sorry for the huge picture)

How could a creek (like the one above) exist at a much larger scale in the in the real world?

The area in question does not need to be on Earth, it could be on a more volcanically active planet, lower gravity, stronger weather, etc.

And just to clarify, if you size down a river, it does not look the same as a creek, so please don't tell me rivers exist, I do realize that.

Comment: The Nile spans for 6600 km, way longer than the creek you were crossing. And also the distance between the riversides is broader than the creek. What exactly are you trying to solve?

Comment: @L.Dutch It's pretty complicated but I'm creating a universe that is an infinite plane, and many different environmental conditions. I was wondering if super-sized biomes were possible, as in exact copies but larger (the nile is a river, not a creek).

Comment: What is the difference between a creek and a river other than size?

Comment: @Thorne If you size down a river does it look like a creek? Not really. Creek water is clearer, and has many larger stones in the water. If you size up a creek the closest comparison would maybe be a canyon river where rocks fell in, but not exactly.

Comment: What if other things like creeks and rocks are normal sized, and you/your character were very small?

Comment: @cyber101 I do have regular sized biomes, but I guess size is relative in an infinite world.

Comment: @NepthysX A larger creek will basically be a river. I think what you want is to have a large river, but have the water condition similar to a creeks. I would like to point out, that the creek image you have, the water looks like its running over rocks and not things like dirt or loose soil which would cloud the water. If you had a large scale river, running through a rocky environment with huge boulders, then there is no reason the water wouldn't also be clear and calm.

Answer (score 1):

### Not really

> Creeks usually are water bodies with narrower channels than rivers.

This tells you that rivers are much "bigger" than creeks.

> Creek - A medium natural waterway, larger than a stream. Often a tributary to a river.

This tells you rivers are larger than creeks. So if you want a larger creek it would turn into a river, on the other hand you will have larger rivers.

> River - A natural stream of water of considerable volume. Larger than all other waterways.

The issue with this is that erosion would erode away rocks leading to it turning into a river.

## Using rivers as an example

1. You start of with a source in the mountains.
2. A stream(travels fast but with a short channel) it moves rocks down into the river while doing this you get smaller rocks which start smashing each other making smaller rocks.
3. The river carries clumps of eroded material which are fine and like mud down to the mouth.

This shows you that you cannot have larger creeks since there will be no large rocks.

Unless you make everything bigger such as rocks to cope with the erosion.

## Sources

https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/what-are-the-differences-between-a-river-and-a-creek.html

http://www.thealmightyguru.com/Pointless/NatureDefinitions.html